# How to apply a git patch when given a pull number

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I downloaded a trunk version of a codebase from git, and there are build errors. Aparently a patch is now available, and I received an email :

see https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/pull/47 for patch

I am new to git so I'm not quite sure what to do with this 'patch' especially, since the page looks more like a discussion thread.

Does anyone know how I can obtain/apply this patch to my locally cloned git repository?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Save the patch somewhere. If you're using linux you can use curl:

```
curl -L https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/pull/47.patch > /tmp/47.patch
```

To apply the patch use `git apply`. You can see if the patch will apply cleanly with the `check` option. Change to your git directory and run:

```
git apply --check /tmp/47.patch
```

If it looks like you want to apply the patch remove the check option

```
git apply /tmp/47.patch
```

Comment: thanks very much for the instructions. I have done exatctly as you said. It seems the patch the wrong one though. FML

Comment: What do you do if the repository is private?  In this case, I'm getting an (expected, but not helpful) 404 when I `curl https://github.com/username/private_repo/pull/42.patch`.  I'm resorting to opening up the patch from my browser and saving it (the horror!)

Comment: To put the commit (including author name, commit comment, etc) in your history, use `git am` rather than `git apply`.

Comment: @Josh, you really puzzled me until I realized you were answering apocryphalauthor, not me.

Comment: @apocryphalauthor , if the repo is private, you can download the patch from within the browser. Just navigate to your pull request and append .patch to the end of the url. That will load the patch in your browser. Then just hit ctrl-s to save it.

Comment: FYI  the `.patch` URL concatenates all the individual commits in the PR branch (relative to whatever the previous commit was at the time) and so may not apply cleanly to the current master. You can use `.diff` to get a diff to the current master.

Answer (score 20):

Just add a `.patch` at the end to get the patch:

https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/pull/47.patch

You can do something like below:

```
$ git checkout master
$ curl http://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/pull/47.patch | git am
$ git push origin master
```

http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/

Answer (score 8):

The rule seems recently changed.

Previously we took a PR and add a `.patch` at the end to get the patch

```
http://github.com/[group]/[project]/pull/30583.patch
```

But now the link is redirect(301) to

```
https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/[group]/[project]/pull/30583.patch
```

So if you use `curl`, you could pipe with `git apply` command to apply a git patch from the Pull Request

```
curl https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/[group]/[project]/pull/30583.patch | git apply
```

If the patch is not right for you now, use `git apply -R` command to rollback the change.

Comment: Add the `-L` argument to curl to have curl follow 301/302 redirects.

Answer (score 5):

To let git download pull request 47 and patch it into `mylocalbranch` locally, run:

```
git checkout -b mylocalbranch
git pull origin pull/47/head
```

If the pull request isn't on the origin repo, run

```
git remote add patchremote https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node
git pull patchremote pull/47/head
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git fetch -q origin +refs/pull/47/merge:
git checkout -qf FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Here you are only fetching and checking out the PR. The OP additionally needs to apply (merge) the PR into his own branch. I'm upvoting anyway, as the fetch command line is a very handy.